# How do I upload a laravel project on cPanel shared hosting?

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel, shared-hosting

I am uploading a simple subscription page for my website using cPanel. I uploaded the files to **public_html**, moved the files from **public** folder and modify **index.php** so it points to the application. The PHP version I used to code this application is **7.3** but I had to select the 7.2 version in the host because that was the latest available.

When I load my website I get this error "This page isn’t working bazzaar.net is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

**When I remove everything from the index.php file and add a simple echo the page loads.**

I really need HELP with this. the error logs are below:

Stack trace:

```
#0 /home3/bazzaar/public_html/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php(198): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response->setStatusCode(500)
#1 /home3/bazzaar/public_html/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php(214): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response->__construct('<!doctype html>...', 500, Array)
#2 /home3/bazzaar/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(328): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::create('<!doctype html>...', 500, Array)
#3 /home3/bazzaar/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(305): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->convertExceptionToResponse(Object(Symfony\Component\Er in /home3/bazzaar/public_html/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php on line 450
```

my **.htacess file**

suPHP_ConfigPath /opt/php72/lib

Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

# Use PHP72 as default

Answer (score 30):

You don't need to make changes to the structure of Laravel. Just copy below htaccess code and paste in .htaccess file at the root of your laravel project.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^$ public/index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 17):

Assuming the cpanel has no other website and your laravel project is supposed to be the default project.

1. Zip your entire Laravel project and export your DB to sql
2. Login to cPanel and navigate to File Manager
3. Ensure you're in the root folder, then click "Upload"
4. Select your zip file and wait for upload to complete
5. Unzip the uploaded file
6. Move the content of public to `public_html` folder
7. Go back to Cpanel and navigate to Databases
8. Created a database and add (create if non exist) a DB user
9. Click on your fresh DB, and click "Import"
10. Select your exported SQL file
11. Try to access your laravel website using the domain url

This website might provide more details https://dev.to/asapabedi/deploying-laravel-5-applications-on-shared-hosting-without-the-use-of-ssh--16a6

Answer (score 16):

I got an effective less painless system for Laravel 8, 9 and 10 version. You can follow, I hope this will help you:

1. In the **public** folder, you will get total 4 files. **.htaccess**, **favicon.ico**, **index.php** and **robots.txt**.
2. Just move all these files to the root of your application, that means, outside the public folder.
3. Open the **index.php** file with editor and change 2 lines.
   Change this line:

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

To:

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

AND Change this line:

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

To:

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

5. If you had images in **public** folder that you used in your application, you will see that throughout the application, your images are not showing.
6. So now go to **.env** file and add this line:

   ```
    ASSET_URL=public
   ```
7. In some cases, admin url could not work. If you see any issue there, you can change the ASSET_URL like this:

   ```
   ASSET_URL=https://yourwebsite.com/public
   ```
8. All tasks are done!

Now just upload your application to the shared server and it will work normally.

Comment: This worked for me on Laravel 10.   On my local development I was deploying it via php artisan serve (xamp on windows).  To simulate public deployment I followed these steps by @arefindev and put all laravel files under a folder in my xamp/htdocs.  It worked!!!!!

Comment: Worked also on Laravel 10

Answer (score 11):

If you are using an Apache server you can do the following simple step

Step 1: just upload your all source code on the server (make sure database & .env
set well)
i) make zip and extract it
ii) deploy code using git or take a clone from a repository and install all
dependencies

Step 2: Make a .htaccess file on the project root directory and copy below code and paste it into this file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```

Comment: It worked for me without copying /public to the root of the app. However, it does not serve public assets (images)

Comment: @MahmoodHussain Yes I will edit the answer once get the proper solution for the assets

Comment: Thank you! This saved me a lot of headaches!

Comment: @MahmoodHussain you can set assets URL in .env file and this way you will able to access the assets easily...

Answer (score 5):

AS OF MAY 2020 LARAVEL 7.0 
This is what worked for me:

1. Update the php version of cpanel to the requirements of laravel version say laravel 7.0 needs https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation
2. Check that all required extensions are installed
3. Then if you are having problems with .htacess, I recommend that you test by..
   creating a simple index.html
   just add a line like

   ## Hello World

   then zip all files in your public_html (including the .htaccess) and upload the index.html 
   refresh the target url say domain.com
   when it works you are ready for the next step
   (if it doesn't try debugging / finding out why)
4. Upload your database (assuming its already exported) by...
   Go to MySQL Databases
   create a database with the exact name of your database to be added 
   then create a MySQL user and give him all priviledges to the database
   Go to phpmyadmin in cpanel and import the exported sql file
5. Zip your working laravel project and upload it to the home folder
6. In cpanel extract and...
   PLEASE NOTE:
   place all folders in the home 
   pick contents of public including .htaccess to public_html

### THE FOLDER AND FILE STRUCTURE SHOULD BE THE SAME AS YOUR LARAVEL PROJECT ON 
YOUR COMPUTER (except public is now public_html)

**WARNING: DON'T TOUCH YOUR index.php or server.php**

7. Make hidden files visible in your cpanel then finally edit the .env file by...
   Only editing DB username and password (I expect the DB name to be the same)
   Also you want to leave APP_DEBUG as true for testing (YOU MUST TEST)
    
   When all is well change it to false
8. If you have no database, what are waiting for refresh already
   Though even with a Database NOWS THE TIME refresh

Answer (score 5):

follow these steps:

1. check .htaccess file on root or subdomain.
2. if move files of public to root => change index.php contents /../ to /

> e.g

> require **DIR**.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

TO

> require **DIR**.'/vendor/autoload.php';

AND

> $app = require_once **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

TO

> $app = require_once **DIR**.'/bootstrap/app.php';

3. check the php version (on laravel 6+ i used php7.4 and problem solved)
4. check .env file

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a new directory named **public_html/myapp** on your host.
2. Inside your Laravel project you have a **public** directory. Copy the content of that **public** directory into the **public_html/myapp** directory you created on your host.
3. On the same level with **public_html** folder (not inside it!), create a new directory named **myapp-laravel** on your host.
4. Excepting the **public** folder, copy every folder and file (ex. **app** folder, **.env** file, ...) from your Laravel project into the **myapp-laravel** folder on your host.
5. Edit the **public_html/myapp/index.php** file like this:

- Change require

  ```
  __ DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
  ```

  to require

  ```
  __ DIR__.'/../../myapp-laravel/vendor/autoload.php';
  ```
- Change

  ```
  require_once __ DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
  ```

  to

  ```
  require_once __ DIR__.'/../../myapp-laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
  ```

Find article [here](https://order-software.com/article/install-laravel-7-app-in-a-subfolder-of-cpanel-host).

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a subdomain on hosting and map it to a folder e.g: "abc"
2. In folder "abc" upload laravel project zip (with vendor folder) then extract it
3. Map subdomain to the public folder of laravel i.e. "abc/public".
4. Create a database & user and assign that user to the database with all privileges
5. Import the DB dump in the database created above.
6. Add DB user/password in laravel .env file.

Note: If you face any due to cache remove file config.php in directory bootstrap/cache.

Answer (score 1):

Most of cpanel have now included a tab for laravel project. just click on the laravel tap and the install, follow simple steps given and setup your folder
[image: screen shot of the tap]
then create index.php file with redirecting power to your public folder having laravel project. ether the following code..

```
  <?php
    header("refresh: 1; https://wesley.io.ke/lara/public/");
    ?>
```

all is done access your project now using the domsin you entered when creating the project

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with PHP version. Laravel 6 requires PHP >=7.2.5 and Hostgator only had 7.1 as the latest version. So i had to contact customer support and ask for the latest PHP version.

Also, **mbStrings** which was a requirement for laravel was turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, upload the project in a folder in your cpanel. in my case it is named `project`. 
Then, upload the public folder in `public_html`, and change the index.php file based on the folder you uploaded your project.

Answer (score -1):

1. zip and upload your project.
2. unzip
3. configure the root folder of your domain to be "public", the public folder inside laravel unzipped folder.