# Laravel url+artisan shows artisans

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I just tried a url on my live site and saw this:
if ı write my url artisan, for examlple `oguzkurukaya.com/artisan`

it shows artisan folder or downloads it. How can disable this?

Comment: It sounds like your website is misconfigured. The document root should point to the public directory, not your main project directory, and there should not be an artisan folder in your public directory.

Comment: so what should ı do on server.php my folders shows public/$url directory what did ı do wrong

Comment: You need to update your site configuration file. If you're using nginx, it would be in /etc/nginx/sites-available, if you're using apache, it would be either under /etc/httpd or /etc/apache2. If you're using Windows, you'll have to find the configuration for whichever webserver you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the root path of your website to `public` folder - which contains index.php file.

Comment: My index.php is on public_html. When ı put it on public_html/public ı cant access any of the urls.How can ı change root path to public folder

Comment: Please check this, it may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61717566